# PDF of Sefer HaAggadah

Tags: jewish-books

I’ve had only a few months ago a pdf of the entire Sefer HaAggadah (Book of Legends) by Bialik that they had online, but now I am unable to find it.

Anyone know any sites that have the entire book online in English?

Comment: It's up on [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/MN40183ucmf_0?q) on the right hand side you can find different file formats (including pdf)